# How to use shell to run a php script

Tags: php, shell, centos, cron

I have a PHP script which fetches new headlines from a website. I would like this PHP script to run at the interval of 11 minutes. I have installed crontab in my CentOS 6.5 machine.
All my PHP script is contained in `/var/www/public/fetch_headlines.php` and I am scheduling my crontab using :

`*/5 * * * * /var/www/public/news_fetcher.sh`

The problem is that to actually enter in `news_fetcher.sh` to call/run the

Comment: Why do you have a `.sh` file in your `www`? What's wrong with just `php /var/www/public/news_fetcher.sh` ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That was just for a quick example. I don't expose my `.sh` file to public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
$ crontab -e
*/5 * * * * YOUR_PHP_PATH /var/www/public/fetch_headlines.php
```

Comment: I will try this, but if I have `php-cli` installed, that means I can replace `/usr/local/bin/php` with it, right?

Comment: Thanks. But can you include an example with how to do it in bash? it is it just the same?